# List users that have posted to a Yammer group

Tags: yammer

Is it possible (via the Yammer REST API or otherwise) to programmatically retrieve a list of all unique users who have posted to a specific Yammer group?

The network in question is a free Yammer network, therefore the data export approach is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to directly get a list of contributors to a group. What you could do is use the messages api to crawl through all of the messages in a group and get the users who sent them. If it's a group with a reasonable number of messages, this shouldn't be that big of a problem. Just don't forget about the rate limits on making api calls.

The message endpoint for a group looks like this.

```
https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/{{group_id}}.json?threaded=extended
```